# Terraform building disks in an unpredictable for vSphere virtual machines

Tags: terraform, vsphere

Trying to add 2 disks to a compute node for docker.. When I use the below stanza, the first 2 servers have the disks flipped.

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "compute" {
    # ...

    disk {
        template = "${var.cloud_template}"
        datastore = "${var.compute_datastore}"
      }

    disk {
      size = "${var.compute_datastore_var_size}"
      name = "${format("compute-var-disk-%s", element(var.compute_names,1))}"
      datastore = "${var.compute_datastore_var}"
    }

    disk {
      template = "${var.cloud_template}"
      datastore = "${var.compute_datastore}"
    }

    disk {
      size = "${var.compute_datastore_var_size2}"
      name = "${format("compute-var-disk2-%s", 
  element(var.compute_names,count.index))}"
      datastore = "${var.compute_datastore_var}"
    }
}
```

In Terraform plan and apply: servers 1&2 have disk 2 at 50gb and disk 3 at 25 (the opposite of what I need), while server 3&4 have them correct.

Any ideas that will help correct this?

Comment: I contemplated using the depends_on clause, but I don't know what or how to make the second disk dependent on the first disk

Comment: Which resource type are you using here? Lots of different resource types have `disk` blocks and I suspect the answer here will depend on which one you're using...

Comment: I've now noticed that the resources are listed in order with a numeric value, how is the value assigned? Example:  disk.2151686800.size:                   "500"  and disk.3070656849.size:                   "30"

Comment: Pardon my ignorance Martin, I'm not sure what your asking. Very new to terraform.

Comment: Just rebuild and computer 1 came out right, but 2, 3, 4 are all switched.. WTH.

Comment: Scott, if you could share the first line of the `resource` block you're working in here, that would give the information I'm looking for. Specifically, you will have something like `resource "foo" "baz" {` ... I would like to know `"foo"`.

Comment: resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "compute" {

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this time there is [an issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10225) in how the `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource is defined in Terraform where the `disk` block is not set to be order-preserving, so the ordering of disks is undefined.

Until that issue is fixed, it's necessary to employ a workaround of looking up disks by their labels or some other available metadata, rather than relying on their attachment at particular indices.

Comment: I have made some minor progress on this..  by changing the section element(var.compute_names,count.index) and using numbers to replace the count.index. I have been able to, at least, build a reproducible order of the disks.